# Trying to check for a certain field inside a firebase firestore document but struggling with the logic behind it

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am using this currently to check and see if a doc exists for a user

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                        let userInfo = db.collection("stripe_customers").doc(user.uid);
```

and then if it does, it runs a script I want

```
userInfo.get().then(function (doc) {
                            if (doc.exists) {
```

However, instead of checking for a specific doc, I need to try and check for a field value inside some documents.

For example I have a collection called "stripe_customers" > that has a document per user via their UID > then inside the document is the collection "charges" > then inside "charges" is a document under a random string of numbers and letters "89nzVNrfQCOVqogDaGvo" for example that is generated by stripe for their charge after they purchase (there may be multiple of these if they have an older charge which is why I need to find the most recent one) > then inside the most recent charge document, I need to check for the field "status" and that is has the value "succeeded". That way I can check to see who has a succeeded payment and if they do it will run the script I want. I am just so confused on how to achieve this. I know how to do basic queries but this is somewhat complex. I need to be able to make sure the current UID has that field with that value so I can see if the current UID paid or not and if they did the script runs, which sets a custom claim.

Here is a visual of my db storage flow for what im trying to do so its easier to understand https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO66S.jpg

Comment: "inside the most recent charge document," -> how do you identify this most recent document in the `charges` sub-collection? Is there a timestamp field in the docs of this collection?

Comment: Yeah the most recent charge document does have a created field and a value with a date ```created: 1582021485``` for example

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what makes this more complex than the simple queries you're already familiar with.  I'm also having a hard time understanding what your data looks like from what you've written here.  It might be easier if you provide a diagram.

Comment: Yeah let me make something visually for you to understand a bit better, give me a few

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NE1x6sU here check this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to get the most recent document in a `charges` (sub)collection based on a `created` field which contains a timestamp value, and check the value of the `status` field of this doc.

The following should do the trick:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
const subCollRef = db.collection("stripe_customers").doc(user.uid).collection("charges");

const query = subCollRef.orderBy('created', 'desc').limit(1);

query.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.size > 0 && snapshot.docs[0].data().status === "succeeded") {
         //payment was succeeded, you can "run your script"
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```